# Parsing Slack Interactive Message POST payload parameter to JSON in Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create an Azure Function to take POST requests from [Slack Message Interactions](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity#components). I'm able to get a test request to come in following [this guide](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/tutorials/local-development) using `ngrok`. However the payload is not coming in like a normal POST request body. Assuming this is because it's a "parameter" payload and not a body.

```js
module.exports = async (context, req) => {
    const { body } = req;
    context.log(body);

    context.res = {
        body,
    };
};
```

Output:

```
payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22block_actions%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22xxx%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22...
```

How do I parse this POST parameter payload into JSON in an Azure Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from this [post](https://www.eliostruyf.com/parse-application-www-form-urlencoded-form-data-azure-function/) I was able to figure this out for my use case.

Using [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) package `npm i qs`

```js
const { parse } = require('qs');

module.exports = async (context, req) => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(parse(req.rawBody).payload);
    context.log(payload);

    context.res = {
        payload,
    };
};
```

Output:

```json
{
  type: 'block_actions',
  user: {
    id: 'xxx',
    username: 'xxx',
    name: 'xxx',
    team_id: 'xxx'
  },
  api_app_id: 'xx',
...
}
```